# How I run a console application from a java console?

Tags: java, console, runtime, exec, runtime.exec

I am messing with Runtime.getRuntime(), but I don't think it really what I want.

I want something that has both user input, and output that goes to stdout.  I would like a whole seperate program to get launched, basically.

Grae

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Answer (score 0):

Doing this:

```
Process process = Runtime.exec( "somecommand.exeorwhatever" );
```

Will run a completely separate process.  Then you can use:

```
InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
InputStream err = process.getErrorStream();
OutputStream out= process.getOutputStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) created with [ProcessBuilder.start()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start%28%29) method and use its input and output streams.

Here is simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] processArgs = new String[]{"ping","google.com"};
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(processArgs).start();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            //I'am using Win7 with PL encoding in console -> "CP852"
            process.getInputStream(), "CP852"));

    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);

    in.close();
    System.out.println("process ended");
}
```